# If statement in .arb files

Tags: android, ios, flutter, internationalization, arb

I have a problem with my mobile application.
I developed my application with flutter and implemented Flutter Internationalization. After creating files with .arb extension I wanted to be able to choose the file by platform ( IOS or Android ) as well as language . Is it possible to use an If statement in the files with .arb extension? Are there any solutions for this problem of mine?

Answer (score 1):

You can put that condition in dart file also.

For ex., `Platform.isAndroid ? "Localization string 1" : "Localization string 2"`

Answer (score 0):

Just do that in your dart file, like this:

```
child: Platform.isAndroid 
  ? Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.stringForAndroid) 
  : Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.otherString)
```